# PHP / Wordpress - dynamic links from php scripts could slow down the site?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a Wordpress blog with the plugin Insert PHP which allows me to execute php code inside posts. All my posts have an image, text and and a link. Sometimes I need to change some links and I don't want to update every time the post content, I have everything organized in a database and I want to get all links dynamically from this database. This is what I thought so far:

**post_links table:**

```
id |            image           |              link            |
1  | http://example.com/1.jpg   | http://example.com/somelink1 |
2  | http://example.com/1.jpg   | http://example.com/somelink2 |
```

**Post content:**

```
<p style="text-align: center;"><img class="aligncenter" src="[insert_php]$id=1; $include "image.php";[/insert_php]" />
<p>Some static text here</p>
<a href="[insert_php]$id=1; $include "link.php";[/insert_php]">My dynamic link</a>
```

**image.php**

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","wordpress");
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT image FROM post_links WHERE id = '$id' LIMIT 1");
echo $result->fetch_object()->image;
?>
```

**link.php**

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","wordpress");
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT link FROM post_links WHERE id = '$id' LIMIT 1");
echo $result->fetch_object()->link;
?>
```

This works fine but my question is: having 2 or 3 additional Mysql requests each time a post is loaded would affect somehow the performance of the whole site? Is there a better way to archive the same result?

Comment: "having 2 or 3 additional Mysql requests each time a post is loaded would affect somehow the performance of the whole site?" - yes, it will slow the site a lot. In what manner can the links and images src be changed? Please give an example.

Comment: I post to wordpress automatically through python-wordpress-xmlrpc, data for posts is taken from the database where lives the table post_links. Links can go offline, so if my python script detect that post with id 1 has "image" link offline, I update the column with a new link. In this way, the wordpress post will always call the updated link for that image

Comment: So, the images are hosted on external servers?

Comment: @user4035 yes like imgur